# existence of infinitely many prime ideals in positive dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring of Krull dimension $\ge 1$. Is 
the spectrum of $R$ always a set of infinite cardinality? I know 
this is the case when $R$ is an affine domain over a field of
characteristic zero. What is the most general case that we can
establish this statement? Proof or reference (purely algebraic please)?

**PS/Edit:** The focus of my question is in the most general case where the statement is true.

Comment: The ring $\Bbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers has dimension $1$, is Noetherian and has only 2 prime ideals. In general, any DVR has these properties.

Comment: Maybe you want $\dim R\ge 2$. In this case your claim holds.

Comment: @user26857: Can you elaborate further? Reference?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334373/noetherian-rings-and-prime-ideals; reference Kaplansky, Theorem 144.

Comment: @user26857: Actually your MSE reference satisfies me fully. Nicely explained!!

Answer (score 1):

It is false. A *discrete valuation domain* (viz. $\mathbf Z_{(p)}$ or $K[[X]]$, $K$ a field) has Krull dimension $1$, and its spectrum has two elements.